# Hightchart change design and functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i try to create hight chart application.i wrote some code and i recived hightchart [like this](http://postimg.org/image/bg462t355/)

this is a my source code

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gkatsarava/Zp3au/1/
```

this is a part my code

```
$(function () {
 Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#05D3F8', '#D1E751', '#25E4BC', '#F3D915', '#FF7E00', '#FF0C96', '#F100F3']});

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'  
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        exporting: {
        enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX'],
            labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize:'10px'
            }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {text: 'TEXT - TEXT'},
            plotLines:[{
            value : 80,
            color: 'red',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
        }],
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:13px;color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: "valuess: {point.y:.2f}%"

        },
        legend: {
                enabled: false,
         },
        labels: {

        },
        plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {

                }
            }
        },
        series: {
        }
    },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'XXXX',
            data: [10],
            id:'1'
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'XXXX',
            data: [40],
            id:'2'
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'XXXX',
            data: [80],
            id:'3'
        }]
    }, function (chart) {

  // bind events to your own custom legend
  $('#my-legend').on('click', 'div', function (e) {
    var el = e.target,
        id = el.getAttribute('data-id'),
        series = chart.get(id);

    series.setVisible(!series.visible);
  });
});
});
```

i have three chart and i want to  unit this all chart in ones. if anyone has experience hightchart help me please .i do not know how i  solved this problem 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you mean by "unit" the charts, but the Highcharts documentation is full of nice examples. Do you want to have something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic) ? It is quite simple, you just have to build your series like in the example.

**EDIT:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xU6XQ/1/) is a fiddle with your data.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Example'
        },
        colors: ['#05D3F8', '#D1E751', '#25E4BC'],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Blue',
            data: [10, 10, 10]

        }, {
            name: 'Yellow',
            data: [40, 40, 40]

        }, {
            name: 'Green',
            data: [80, 80, 80]

        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: meybe you did not understand me. i want to recive like this result(http://postimg.org/image/f6s29dx2x/)

Comment: If the issue was just the red dashed lines, you should have said it explicitly in the first place...